# Python 'String reversing' program

Tags: python, string

This is a simple program to reverse a string:
When I enter a string,say 'hello', I'm getting output as 'olle'.
The last character is not getting displayed.

```
    word=raw_input('Enter any word:')
    l=len(word)
    n=l-1
    reverse=""
    while True:
          n-=1
          if n>=1 or n==0:
             get=word[n]
             reverse=str(reverse)
             reverse=reverse+get
             continue
          elif n!=0:
             print('\n The word:',reverse)
             break
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This** is a **simple** program to reverse a string:

```
print word[::-1]
```

Comment: Not technically an answer but an upvote for the lol it provided.

Comment: I will not say that this is `not` an answer..:)

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me as though your problem is that you are doing this:

```
n=l-1
reverse=""
while True:
      n-=1
```

That means that you are subtracting from `n` twice before you do anything, meaning the first letter of your word is removed before you reverse it.

Try removing the first of those lines.

Comment: `n=l-1` is to subtract one from the length of the string.
Because, for 'hello', 'o' will be in 4th position whereas length of the string is 5. 
So it results in `out of range exception`

Comment: Yes, but then you are _doing the same thing again inside your loop_ before you first take any letters out of the word, which is why the first letter of your reversed string is the second letter of the word.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> ''.join(reversed('hello'))
'olleh'
```

Comment: If you're going to depart from the OP's method (and thereby actual question he's asking), @eumiro's `str[::-1]` is far more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are decrementing n at the beginning of your loop rather than the end. That said, there are much shorter and more Pythonic ways to do this. Maybe try

`word[::-1]`